# How to safely drop Compact SQL database migration history

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a WPF app utilizing a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database. For the course of this project, we made several changes in the model structure with a number of code-based and later with automatic migrations. They all are stored in the `_MigrationHistory` table and represented by several migration classes.

Now it appeared that I need to considerably change the model. Since the app is still in the development phase, dropping data in the database is not a concern. I would like to get rid of the whole previous migration history and start a new clean model. So my question is what steps are to remove the whole history of migrations and start a new history with automatic migrations in the future.

What parts of the project must be deleted and how to do it safely?

Answer (score 0):

**First Make sure your project is backed up and your database is also backed up. In case something goes wrong.**

If your project is setup using **entity framework code first**,

In the project you can delete all the migration files in the 'Migrations' folder except 'MigrationConfiguration.cs' contained within the project that is using entity framework.

Also if you are not concerned with dropping the database, then go-ahead and delete the entire database, then create a new one with the same name that is configured in your database context connection string found in your project's config file.

Rebuild your solution and create a new migration by typing the command in the package manager console 'add-migration' and provide a name.  This will create a new migration to create the database for all your code first models.  If the generated migration file looks correct, then run 'update-database' in the package manager to apply the migration to your empty database.

Comment: Thank you, srfigie. That worked. After rebuilding the app, it created a correct empty database. One question though. I configured the migration configuration class for automatic migrations since I don't need tracking any future changes and possible downgrading. So I believe I don't have to  use the suggested package manager console commands. Is that correct?